# Кросс-платформенная компиляция c++

Tags: c++, компиляция, кроссплатформенность

Возможно ли скомпилировать файл (динамическую библиотеку), которая может выполняться на всех ОС (Windows/Linux/MacOS)? Если да, то как?

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Будь это так просто, все приложения давно были бы кроссплатформенными.

Comment: в теории через mingw32/64 можно для Windows в Linux собрать.

Comment: @AivanF. Тащемта можно, как минимум один антивирусный движок является MZPE-файлом и работает как в винде, так и в линухе.

Answer (score 4):

Скомпилировать библиотеку в виде единого файла, который будет работать везде, не получится. Дело в том, что в каждой операционной системе СВОЙ формат исполняемых файлов и файлов библиотек (читайте доки по ключевым словам - MZ, PE, ELF, a.out)

С другой стороны, существуют системы, позволяющие запускать "не родные" программы. Одной из них является wine. Она входит в практически любой дистрибутив Linux и позволяет запускать windows-приложения. Правда, это не абсолютное решение проблемы.

Comment: Дополнительно такую вещь скажу. Собрать исполняемый файл под Windows, например, на Linux возможно. Это и называется "кросс-компиляцией": т.е. целевая платформа отличается от платформы, где собирается код. Но это ни разу не означает, что собранный код будет запускаться на той платформе, где собирался...

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Если ваша программа не будет иметь никаких внешних зависимостей и вы будете руками загружать ее в неродной ОС и передавать на нее управление.